# What is an example of a Hashtable implementation in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, hashtable

I realize C# and .NET in general already has the Hashtable and Dictionary classes.

Can anyone demonstrate in C# an implementation of a Hashtable?

**Update:** To clarify, I'm not ncessarily looking for a complete implementation, just an example of the core features of a hashtable (i.e. add,remove, find by key).

Comment: I know it's an old question, but I've actually bothered to implement a simple HashTable in 62 lines of code that does Add and Find.

Comment: in 2015 you can find it [here](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/hashtable.cs)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is also the Mono version of the class libraries of course:

- [System.Collections.Hashtable](https://github.com/mono/mono/tree/mono-3.0.3/mcs/class/corlib/System.Collections/Hashtable.cs?view=markup)
- [System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary](https://github.com/mono/mono/tree/mono-3.0.3/mcs/class/corlib/System.Collections.Generic/Dictionary.cs?view=markup)

Comment: @longda they should be fixed now

Comment: Thanks @danfromisrael, they should be fixed again. I linked to a tag this time, so hopefully that will be safe for a bit longer.

Answer (score 131):

Long after the question has been asked, so I don't expect to earn much rep. However I decided it would be fun to write my own very basic example (in less than 90 lines of code):

```
    public struct KeyValue<K, V>
    {
        public K Key { get; set; }
        public V Value { get; set; }
    }

    public class FixedSizeGenericHashTable<K,V>
    {
        private readonly int size;
        private readonly LinkedList<KeyValue<K,V>>[] items;

        public FixedSizeGenericHashTable(int size)
        {
            this.size = size;
            items = new LinkedList<KeyValue<K,V>>[size];
        }

        protected int GetArrayPosition(K key)
        {
            int position = key.GetHashCode() % size;
            return Math.Abs(position);
        }

        public V Find(K key)
        {
            int position = GetArrayPosition(key);
            LinkedList<KeyValue<K, V>> linkedList = GetLinkedList(position);
            foreach (KeyValue<K,V> item in linkedList)
            {
                if (item.Key.Equals(key))
                {
                    return item.Value;
                }
            }

            return default(V);
        }

        public void Add(K key, V value)
        {
            int position = GetArrayPosition(key);
            LinkedList<KeyValue<K, V>> linkedList = GetLinkedList(position);
            KeyValue<K, V> item = new KeyValue<K, V>() { Key = key, Value = value };
            linkedList.AddLast(item);
        }

        public void Remove(K key)
        {
            int position = GetArrayPosition(key);
            LinkedList<KeyValue<K, V>> linkedList = GetLinkedList(position);
            bool itemFound = false;
            KeyValue<K, V> foundItem = default(KeyValue<K, V>);
            foreach (KeyValue<K,V> item in linkedList)
            {
                if (item.Key.Equals(key))
                {
                    itemFound = true;
                    foundItem = item;
                }
            }

            if (itemFound)
            {
                linkedList.Remove(foundItem);
            }
        }

        protected LinkedList<KeyValue<K, V>> GetLinkedList(int position)
        {
            LinkedList<KeyValue<K, V>> linkedList = items[position];
            if (linkedList == null)
            {
                linkedList = new LinkedList<KeyValue<K, V>>();
                items[position] = linkedList;
            }

            return linkedList;
        }
    }
```

Here's a little test application:

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            FixedSizeGenericHashTable<string, string> hash = new FixedSizeGenericHashTable<string, string>(20);

            hash.Add("1", "item 1");
            hash.Add("2", "item 2");
            hash.Add("dsfdsdsd", "sadsadsadsad");

            string one = hash.Find("1");
            string two = hash.Find("2");
            string dsfdsdsd = hash.Find("dsfdsdsd");
            hash.Remove("1");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

It's not the best implementation, but it works for Add, Remove and Find. It uses [chaining](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table#Separate_chaining) and a simple modulo algorithm to find the appropriate bucket.

Comment: I'm aware that this question and answer are quite old, but i'll take this longshot. Shouldn't insert \ delete \ find operations be of O(n) efficiency?

Comment: no..find is only O(n) worst case (all keys hash to the same value..not very likely hehe), but expected case is constant.  Insert and Delete are both constant since you just create the hash and insert/remove it from that index in the array..there is no iterating over the elements.

Comment: Sure you can look at real world implementations of Hash based collections but this example is clean and great for understanding the algorithm. It emphasizes usage of GetHashCode and Equals methods that is very important for grasping the mechanics of HashMap. Thanks a lot for this answer.

Comment: @Puterdo Borato thanks. I'm amazed how many upvotes this answer has had. You are right though- there aren't many simple implementations out there

Comment: @RichardOD nice work. however, in the Add() method you might want to check if the key already exists.

Comment: If you refer the MSDN documentation about GetHashCode(), it mentions as 

"The default implementation of the GetHashCode method does not guarantee unique return values for different objects.... the default implementation of this method must not be used as a unique object identifier for hashing purposes."

Value types must override this method to provide a hash function that is appropriate for that type and to provide a useful distribution in a hash table".


Refer https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gethashcode(v=vs.100).aspx for more info.

Comment: @BharatMallapur GetHashCode() is fine for a simple implementation of a hashtable, since the hash code is not actually being used as a unique identifier. It just needs to get you to the right linked list that you then iterate through to find the node you want.

Comment: I wanted to brush up on some data structures, So I wanted to see a simple implementation and this is just perfect thank you!

Comment: We are in 2019 still this solution goes long way to clear the concept. Thanks

Answer (score 9):

Have you looked at the [C5 collections](http://www.itu.dk/research/c5/)? You can [download the source](http://www.itu.dk/research/c5/Release1.1/C5.src.zip) which includes a hash table.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I was hoping for a small basic example of Add/Remove with the hashing modulo including, but not sure if that will fill the entire page

Answer (score 8):

You can see how the .NET Hashtable is implemented (for example in C#) using reflector

http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/

Answer (score 2):

You could also look at the Hashtable implementation from [Mono](http://www.go-mono.com) here:

http://anonsvn.mono-project.com/viewvc/trunk/mcs/class/corlib/System.Collections/Hashtable.cs?revision=111788&view=markup